# tomcat not generating hprof file on outofmemory error

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, heap-dump, hprof

I have some memory leak issue in my web app which is deployed in tomcat. To find the root cause I enabled the HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory error by setting:

> -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/usr/local/tomcat/logs

and the memory settings in the tomcat is:

> -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

When the out of memory issue happened, I see

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

on the tomcat log file, but the .hprof file is not generated. Am I missing some settings here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @beny23 wrote you should use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

and as is stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html):

> The -XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Option This option tells the Java
>   HotSpot VM to generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java
>   heap or the permanent generation cannot be satisfied. There is no
>   overhead in running with this option, so it can be useful for
>   production systems where the OutOfMemoryError exception takes a long
>   time to surface.

Check also your Java version since this option was [introduced](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) in 1.4.2 update 12, 5.0 update 7.

Comment: What's the source of the quote?

Comment: Resource is from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html